# new T(x, y, z) as a function

Tags: c++, stl

I have some code that wants a function pointer, but I need to call it with something that
does "new T(x, y, z)".

I can write a function along the lines of:

```
template<T, X, Y, Z>
T* Construct(X x, Y y, Z z) {
   return new T(x, y, z);
}
```

but I wonder if such a thing exists already in STL, since I need to do this for variable number of arguments and this requires repeating the above, say, 10 times, once for each number of arguments, and I'd like to avoid adding so much boilerplate to the header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11 you can use variadic templates:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T* Construct(Args&&... args)
{
    return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Also, consider whether you really want to return a raw pointer and not a smart pointer (for instance, a `unique_ptr`. Unless you're doing low-level stuff, using owning raw pointers is discouraged in Modern C++.

Comment: And, of course, `return std::make_<unique/shared>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);`

Comment: Thanks, that sort of works, but not in the way I anticipated. I am still curious if this exact function already exists in the STL. The reason why your solution doesn't quite work for me is that I am not (yet) permitted to use variadic templates in my codebase. If this function was already in STL I could use it.

Comment: @user2557021: Then you may want to consider Kerrek's solution

Comment: Re: Chris' comment, I basically want something like make_unique that returns a raw pointer. And I can't write my own because I can't use variadic templates until they are approved for this codebase. I know, it's a ridiculous problem to have:) Maybe I'll just wait until they are approved.

Comment: @user2557021: Or just write those 10 versions and replace them with a single variadic template when variadic templates will be approved. Clients won't have to be changed.

Comment: @user2557021: You can provide some overloads for, say, up to 5 arguments. I do this sometimes when using MSVC (which does not have variadic templates).

Comment: You know, it turns out that variadic templates have actually already been approved for us, so your solution works perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what the standard allocator does:

```
#include <memory>

std::allocator<T> alloc;

T * p = alloc.allocate(1);
alloc.construct(p, x, y, z);
```

Comment: Thanks. See my comments for Andy's solution. This works, except I need to have a function that does this, and it will necessarily have to be a variadic template. I can only use one that already exists as a function or method in the STL. It sounds like there isn't one.